# Excel: How to force cell evaluation

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a  list of start times that need to be converted to 24 hour format.  I changed the format for the entire column, but i have to press Enter for every row for excel to apply the new format.

Is there a was i can force excel to evaluate the cell format and change it.  I have few thousand rows.

[image]

Comment: I can't replicate the problem in Excel 2007.    If I highlight the range and change the format, all highlighted entries are changed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it bugs me too.

```vb
dim c as range
for each c in application.intersect(activesheet.usedrange, activesheet.columns("C"))
  c.value = c.value
next
```

Comment: that worked great!

Comment: you're right, none of the usual methods work.

Comment: did not work for me. Excel 16.60 on mac

Answer (score 2):

If all your cells have some text in common, you can also do a find/replace - in your case find every ":", and replace it with a ":" (i.e. find a way to find/replace that does nothing), and excel will re-format the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Another workaround is:

1. Put value 1 in any unused cell on the sheet
2. Copy the cell
3. Select the range you wish to force-evaluate
4. Past special - Values + Multiply